Pointwise limit of continuous functions whose graph is in a given closed set
Let $C\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ be a closed set with the property that for every $x\in\mathbb R$, there exists at least one $y\in\mathbb R$ such that $(x,y)\in C$.
Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ of Baire class 1 such that $(x,f(x))\in C$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$?

EDIT #1: I guess the “Close” vote is because I hadn’t provided more details or outlined an attempt. That is because my hunch was originally split 50–50 between whether the conjecture is true or not. After thinking about it more, I now slightly lean towards thinking the claim is true, at least when the projection of $C$ onto the $y$-axis is compact (so that any counterexample doesn’t hinge on unbounded things).
One particular counterexample I tried constructing was based on the closed topologist’s sine curve. It turns out that that doesn’t work as a counterexample. In particular, let $C$ be the graph of the curve and define $f(x)\equiv\sin(1/x)$ for each $x\in(0,1]$ and let $f(0)\equiv y\in[-1,1]$ be arbitrary. One can construct a sequence $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ of continuous functions that converges pointwise to $f$ as follows. Define, for each $m\in\mathbb N$, $f_m(0)\equiv y$, and let $f_m(x)$ coincide with $f(x)$ for $x\in[1/m,1]$. Then, draw a linear interpolation between $(0,y)$ and $(1/m,f(1/m))$.

EDIT #2: Intuitively, the question is (roughly):
Is it true that every closed (or at least compact) set in the plane is arbitrarily close to the graph of some continuous function?

I suspect this is related to uniformization results in descriptive set theory. I don't have time now to look into this, but perhaps this google search will help -- descriptive + set + theory + "uniformization"

The "property that for every $x\in\mathbb R$, there exists at least one $y\in\mathbb R$ such that $(x,y)\in C$." implies that $C$ is not compact.

@MichaelGreinecker You’re right. I edited the question slightly, potentially imposing compactness on the projection of $C$ instead.

I’ve thought a lot about this problem and finally managed to prove a generalized result that I’ve found to be non-trivial, exciting, and challenging. I document the result and my approach below.

THEOREM: Let $X$ be an arbitrary metric space, $n$ a positive integer, and $\Gamma$ a correspondence that maps from $X$ into $\mathbb R^n$. This means that for every $x\in X$, $\Gamma(x)$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Suppose that $\Gamma$ has a closed graph, which means that $$\operatorname{Gr}(\Gamma)\equiv\{(x,y)\in X\times\mathbb R^n\,|\,y\in\Gamma(x)\}$$ is closed in the product topology. Then, there exists what I term an “approximately continuous selector”: a function $f:X\to\mathbb R^n$ with the property that

$f(x)\in\Gamma(x)$ for every $x\in X$; and
there exists a sequence $(f_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ of functions such that $f_m:X\to\mathbb R^n$ is continuous for every $m\in\mathbb N$; and
$\lim_{m\to\infty}f_m(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in X$ pointwise.


By Theorem 24.10 in Kechris (1995, p. 192), the pointwise-limit-of-continuous-functions property is implied by the following condition: for every open $U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, the inverse image $f^{-1}(U)\equiv\{x\in X\,|\,f(x)\in U\}$ is $F_{\sigma}$ (a countable union of closed sets) in $X$. To establish the existence of such a selector, I first defined the following alternative metric $\rho$ on $\mathbb R^n$: $$\rho(x,y)\equiv\frac{\|x-y\|}{1+\|x-y\|}\quad\text{for every $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$,}$$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm. This metric always assumes a distance of less than $1$, and it generates the same topology on $\mathbb R^n$ as does the Euclidean distance. In particular, $\mathbb R^n$ is $\rho$-separable, and even $\rho$-complete. (In general, completeness may not be preserved by switching to a different metric generating the same topology, so this needed to be double-checked separately.)
The key first step in the proof is to recognize that for any $A\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, one has the following equality: $$\{x\in X\,|\,\Gamma(x)\cap A\text{ is not empty}\}=\operatorname{Proj}_X(\operatorname{Gr}(\Gamma)\cap(X\times A)),$$ where $\operatorname{Proj}_X(\cdot)$ denotes projection of a product set to the coordinates corresponding to $X$. Next, observe that the closed-graph property implies that for any open $U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, the set $$\{x\in X\,|\,\Gamma(x)\cap U\text{ is not empty}\}=\operatorname{Proj}_X(\operatorname{Gr}(\Gamma)\cap(X\times U))$$ is $F_{\sigma}$ in $X$. (Since $U$ is an open subset of a Euclidean space, it is $F_{\sigma}$ in $\mathbb R^n$. One needs to be a little careful here, because the projection of a product-closed set need not be closed, but the projection of a product-compact set is compact. In this step, the $\sigma$-compactness of $\mathbb R^n$ comes in handy.)
The rest of the proof essentially imitates the (abstruse but intimidatingly elegant) inductive arguments in the following sources:

the proof of Kuratowski and Ryll-Nardzewski’s measurable-selection theorem in Aliprantis and Border (2006, pp. 600–601); and
the discussion of Section 1.2 in Jayne and Rogers (2002, pp. 8–13).


If all sets of the form $C(x)=\{y\mid(x,y)\in C\}$ are compact, there is a simple positive solution: Just take $f$ to be given by $f(x)=\max C(x)$. Then $f$ is upper-semicontinuous and, therefore, a Baire 1 function as the pointwise limit of a decreasing sequence of continuous functions.

Thank you (belatedly) for your answer. However, I don’t think that the upper semicontinuity of $f$ is guaranteed. Let $C\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ be the graph of the function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined as
\begin{align*}
g(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{x}&\text{if $x\in\mathbb R\setminus{0}$,}\0&\text{if $x=0$.}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then, $C(x)={g(x)}$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$ and hence $f=g$. But $f$ is not upper semicontinuous (although it is a function of Baire class $1$).

You are right. It works under the stronger assumption that there is for each $x$ an open neighborhood $U$ and a compact set $K$  such that $C(x')\subseteq K$ for all $x'\in U$. Then, $C$ is the graph of an upper hemicontinuous and compact-valued correspondence.
